# Exportar hoja de Excel a PDF por macro

Tags: excel, vba

tengo el siguiente código en excel y vba para exportar mi hoja a PDF

```
Sub ImprimirPdf()
Dim NumeroDocumento As String
Dim RutaArchivo As String



    NumeroDocumento = Right("000" & Range("F6"), 4)
    RutaArchivo = "C:\Users\etestin\Documents\Informes\Informe " & NumeroDocumento & ".pdf"
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=RutaArchivo, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    


End Sub
```

El problema es que no se como seleccionar horientación horizontal, Tamaño A3 y ajustar al 75% del tamaño normal.

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes intentar configurar las opciones la hoja como a continuación
antes de guardar como PDF

```
Sub ImprimirPdf()
    Dim NumeroDocumento As String
    Dim RutaArchivo As String
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA5
       .Zoom = 75
    End With
    NumeroDocumento = Right("000" & Range("F6"), 4)
    RutaArchivo = "C:\Users\etestin\Documents\Informes\Informe " & NumeroDocumento & ".pdf"

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=RutaArchivo, OpenAfterPublish:=True



End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Funciona perfecto.